# WebMatrix Session variables not working

Tags: c#, session-variables, webmatrix

due to an oversight on my part (still new to AppState and Session variables) I have to change all of my AppStates to Session variables.  WebMatrix's replace has made that part easy, however I am now getting this error on the first of the two lines of code below:

```
Session["gActionMessage"] = "";
Session["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
```

Error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

If it matters, these lines of code are in my _AppStart.cshtml file.

Any suggestions?  Do I have the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are not available at the point that the _AppStart.cshtml file is executed. That happens too early in the pipeline. You can use _PageStart.cshtml to initialise session variables.

Comment: Yeah, I finally saw that in my research last night.  I can't believe how hard it was to find.  I found it on mikesdotnetting (Mike Brind's site).  I had to search for my suspicion that Session variables couldn't be started in _AppStart altogether.  Thank you for the verification, sir, they are working great now!

Comment: Mike Brind's Site:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages